# Why i can not move this dialogBox in GWT?

Tags: gwt, dialog

Below is part of my code, i donot know why it can not be moved . Can somebody help me out?

Thank you!

```
<div class="sidePanel" style="margin:8px 0">
                        <div class="header">Problem List</div>
                        <sidebar:SidebarProblemListWidget ui:field="problemListWidget" debugId="problemListWidget"/>
                       <g:DialogBox autoHideEnabled="false" modal="true">
                        <g:HTMLPanel>
                                <div class="{style.pl}">
                                    <g:Button ui:field="btnOne" addStyleNames="{style.round-button}" visible="false">1</g:Button>
                                </div>

                                <div class="{style.brtn}">
                                    <g:Button ui:field="btnTwo" addStyleNames="{style.round-button}" visible="false" >2</g:Button>
                                </div>

                                <div class="{style.brtn}">
                                    <g:Button ui:field="integrityActivator" addStyleNames="{style.round-button}">OK</g:Button>

                                </div>
                                <div class="{style.brtn}">
                                    <g:Button ui:field="btnThree" addStyleNames="{style.round-button}" visible="false">3</g:Button>
                                </div>

                                <div class="{style.btn}">
                                    <g:Button ui:field="btnFour" addStyleNames="{style.round-button}" visible="false">4</g:Button>

                                </div>

                        </g:HTMLPanel>
                       </g:DialogBox>

                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

DialogBox can be dragged by its caption. You don't specify a caption in this code.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have one more question, can i specify a caption in this ui file? or i have to give this dialogBox a ui field and specify there?

Comment: <g:DialogBox autoHideEnabled="false" modal="true">
                           <g:caption>Test</g:caption>
                        <g:HTMLPanel>
                                <div class="{style.pl}">
                                    <g:Button ui:field="btnOne" addStyleNames="{style.round-button}" visible="false">1</g:Button>
                                </div>
This is not correct... i still can not move it

Comment: I think i fix it by adding a ui field for that ! Thank you so much Andrei

Comment: I just have one more question,  can i drag anywhere else to move the dialogbox? i do not want to drag it by its caption

Comment: There is an example in the documentation for setting a caption in UIBinder: http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DialogBox.html

Comment: No, only the caption implements the interfaces necessary for drag behavior.